# Bind name of image resource

Tags: c#, wpf, image, binding, staticresource

I have pictures in the windows resources:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <BitmapImage x:Key="Image1"  UriSource="../Resources/MyImages/Image1.png" />
    <BitmapImage x:Key="Image2"  UriSource="../Resources/MyImages/Image2.png" />
    <BitmapImage x:Key="Image3"  UriSource="../Resources/MyImages/Image3.png" />
</Window.Resources>
```

Their names match the names that I have in enum object in the model.

```
    private ImagesEnum _currentImage;
    public ImagesEnum CurrentImage
    {
        get { return _currentImage; }
        set
        {
            if (_currentImage!= value)
            {
                _currentImage= value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("CurrentImage");
            }
        }
    }
```

the enum:

```
public enum ImagesEnum 
{
    Image1,
    Image2,
    Image3
}
```

I want to bind the name of the resource with the name that I have in the enum object.

Something like this:

```
<Image  Source="{StaticResource {Binding CurrentImage}}" />
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `CurrentImage` is of type `ImagesEnum` and represent the current image to show, you can use a value converter:

```
public class ImagesEnumToSourceConverter: IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if(value is ImagesEnum)
        {
            switch((ImagesEnum)value)
            {
                case ImagesEnum.Image1:
                    return "../Resources/MyImages/Image1.png";
                case ImagesEnum.Image2:
                    return "../Resources/MyImages/Image2.png";
                case ImagesEnum.Image3:
                    return "../Resources/MyImages/Image3.png";
            }
        }
        return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
    }
}
```

Your binding should be:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <conv:ImagesEnumToSourceConverter x:Key="ImagesEnumToSource" />
</Window.Resources>

.....

<Image Source="{Binding CurrentImage, Converter={StaticResource ImagesEnumToSource}}" />
```